# cond clause for optional arguments

Tags: conditionals

Am using an optional argument and want to use `cond` to execute `(do-this)` if actm is present and matches `'regexp`, and `(do-that)` otherwise.  Is the following the correct way to do it, or am I missing something?

```
(defun kmsec (&optional actm)
  "Identify comment category ';; [Category]'."
  
(cond

   ((eq actm 'regexp)
       (do-this))

   (t
       (do-that)) ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one way to do it.  Given that there are only two alternatives, another way to do it is:

```lisp
(defun kmsec (&optional actm)
  "Identify comment category ';; [Category]'."
  
  (if (eq actm 'regexp)
      (do-this)
    (do-that)))
```